# Trying to merge 2 PDF files and be ADA compliant

Tags: c#, pdf, accessibility, adobe

I need to create a merged PDF file in C#.  This is checked in Adobe Acrobat Pro to see if its ADA compliant.  Here is my code. I am using iTextSharp to create the file.  [image]

Comment: I am trying to merge two pdfs which are ADA compliant but after merging, the output file is not remains ADA compliant.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to have multiple errors

1. PDF reader is not closed.
2. You are using itextsharp.text.image -- which will get the image that is not ADA-compliant.

You can use the solution mentioned in this ref link: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/merge-number-of-pdf-into-a-single-pdf-using-itextsharp/

Comment: Added the closes and changes in the link but still not ADA compliant on merged PDFs.